# Android app no longer starts from Visual Studio after referencing C++ project

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm building a cross-platform Xamarin app and it has been working fine. However, I need to implement some logic in C++ and therefore created a *shared Android/iOS project*.

The C++ Android project targets the same Android API version as the app project.

If I reference the C++ project (to get the **.so** file in my Android app project) the app fails to start.

It seems to build fine, and I see `Starting Android application ...` in the Visual Studio output, but then it just seems to exit without any additional info. In other words, the app is deployed, but it isn't started and the debugger isn't attached.

If I remove the reference again, the app starts normally.

I'm targeting x86 with the C++ library, same architecture as the emulator.

Comment: It'd be better to answer your own question than editing the solution into the question

Comment: I'm not sure it's a solution yet, though. I removed that edit. :)